# Clear the history of a webview via a preferenceActivity?

Tags: android

I have set up a preferenceActivity in my app, and I have added a . When that preference is clicked, I want to erase the history of the webview I have in my main activity.

How can I do this? I cannot create a link to the webview from the preference activity as it isn't on the screen, and using `MyActivity.wv.clearHistory();` doesn't work.

So, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I still encountered situations where the history wouldn't be cleared if I did it in 'onPageFinished', so I ended up doing it in 'onProgressChanged' in the WebChromeClient:

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
  public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
    if (progress == 100 && mClearWebViewOnPageLoaded) {
      view.clearHistory();
      mClearWebViewOnPageLoaded = false;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: How exactly does this answer the question?

Comment: My question is how to call the clearHistory command from a preferenceActivity. I cannot call clearHistory from a preferenceActivity. This does not answer the question.

Comment: use Like  this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638775/webview-clearcache-from-preferenceactivity